# Preview any uploaded image in android

Tags: android, android-studio, file-upload, android-image

I am making an activity in Android Studio using Kotlin in which the user can upload his document in image form on the server. So what I want is that the user after uploading the image can see a link kind of thing like the one shown in the image below, clicking on which the user can see the image that they have uploaded. Any idea how that can be done?? I had used the Intent method wherein I passed the image Uri and did the whole process but in that case I am getting an error saying "media not found", maybe coz I had used a third party library(canhub image cropper) to crop the image so android might not be able to locate the image (**I have the URI of the image with me)

[image]

Answer (score 2):

What you can do is create a custom xml layout file(lets call it image_preview.xml) and add a ImageView in it.
After that when you click the "link kind of thing" you can inflate image_preview.xml using a Dialog or AlertDialog and pass the uri to the ImageView.
I hope this code snippet helps you.

**image_preview.xml**

```
<androidx.constraintlayout.widget.ConstraintLayout 
xmlns:android="http://schemas.android.com/apk/res/android"
android:layout_width="wrap_content"
android:layout_height="wrap_content"
xmlns:app="http://schemas.android.com/apk/res-auto">

<ImageView
    android:id="@+id/imageView"
    android:layout_width="wrap_content"
    android:layout_height="wrap_content"
    app:layout_constraintTop_toTopOf="parent"
    app:layout_constraintStart_toStartOf="parent"/>
</androidx.constraintlayout.widget.ConstraintLayout>
```

**Custom Dialog code**

```
public void loadImagePreView(Uri yourImageUri) {
    AlertDialog.Builder alertDialog = new AlertDialog.Builder(this);
    View customView = getLayoutInflater().inflate(R.layout.user, null);
    alertDialog.setView(customView);

    ImageView imageView = customView.findViewById(R.id.imageView);
    imageView.setImageURI(yourImageUri); // enter your uri here

    AlertDialog dialog = alertDialog.create();
    dialog.show();
}
```